# how to convert a html 5 web app into ipa file and test it on ipad

Tags: html, ipad, ipa, iphone-web-app

i have html 5 web app it is working fine on browser on samasung galaxy and ipad browser but i want it to convert it in ipa file and install that web app on ipad to see how it works.
so is there any way to convert a web app of html into ipa file.

Comment: I think easiest will be to use AppGyver or Trigger.io to achieve what you need to do.